# Looking for a module similar to "Read and Understood" that I can use for Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I would like to be able to create a "Book" on my site and have the users check each and every single page of the book they read; without being able to skip pages and locking them on the page they are.

I found the module [Read and Understood](https://www.drupal.org/project/read_and_understood) to be good for this, however, it is only supported on Drupal 6.x.

I also found [Sign for acknowledgement](https://www.drupal.org/project/acknowledgements) but does not have the "No return" functionality like Read and Understood" does ("No return" option so users are locked into their agreement).

Any idea of any other module that I could use instead, that is supported on Drupal 7.x sites?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought of using Rules module for this?  I think you could set a Rule to control which pages the user can visit based on whether they have checked the box?